# email issue in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart-events

An order confirmation email is sent for canceled/failed payments

User reach to the payment gateway, when reached to the cart after selecting final and reach to the payment page and user cancel the order but a successful email sent to the user did somebody face this issue before my open cart version 3.0

didn`t check the code yet, please tell me,

2) My website home page icons change into some encrypted boxes whenever some body visit my website first time later on user go in and visit some other pages and revisit the website home page, icons looks fine ,i refer so many links, even try to make changes in  .htaccess file as well but nothing works,is there any way that i can fix it,i am providing my website site link,if you want because this issue never comes on local server,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d19Ak.jpg),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUlwE.png)

Comment: "didn`t check the code yet, please tell me" don't be lazy.

Comment: Hey paul,thanks for the help,for now the issue resolved,still i have some other issues as well,could you please help me with this issue as well,whenever some new person visit my website the icons change into encrypted boxes after that user goes inside someother pages and comeback to the homepage,icons came back and looks fine, i have make changes in .htaccess and try some other suggestion which i find on website but nothing works,i can provide you my website link if you want,for now i attached my website homepage screenshots

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is the order states options (system -> settings -> options). What state do the orders get when a payment is cancelled? Is the state unchecked for the 'order ready' states in the options?

Answer (score 0):

This mainly depends on payment extension. Payment extension is responsible of setting correct `order_status_id` depending from 'error', 'failed', 'not completed' methods.

Sometimes, payment module has incorrect return callback links.

Again, check payment module methods.